# How to effiectively substitute the member in list with their order?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning

Now I have a long number list, for example

```
a = {{1020, 3058}, {98, 98}, {599, 600}}; (*just a sample, the list is very very long*)
```

I want to replace the number with their order in the list. The number `98` is the smallest number so it should be replaced with `1` and so on. After replacement the list `a` should be

```
{{4, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}};
```

The code I use is

```
a = {{1020, 3058}, {98, 98}, {599, 600}};
b = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@a;
rule = Table[b[[i]] -> i, {i, 1, Length@b}];
a /. rule
```

or

```
a = {{1020, 3058}, {98, 98}, {599, 600}};
b = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@a;
Cases[a, {x_Integer, y_Integer} :> {Position[b, x][[1, 1]], Position[b, y][[1, 1]]}]
```

With the increase of the list size, the code above is very time-consuming. I want to know if there some efficient way to realize my need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is much faster:

```
a = {{1020, 3058}, {98, 98}, {599, 600}};
b = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@a;
a /. Dispatch@Thread[b -> Range@Length@b]
(* {{4, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}} *)
```

To wit:

```
SeedRandom[0]
a = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {10000, 2}];
test1 = a /. Dispatch@Thread[b -> Range@Length@b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
test2 = a /. Thread[b -> Range@Length@b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
test3 = Cases[a, {x_Integer, y_Integer} :> {Position[b, x][[1, 1]], Position[b, y][[1, 1]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
test4 = a /. Table[b[[i]] -> i, {i, 1, Length@b}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.020565 *)
(* 2.091893 *)
(* 1.335496 *)
(* 1.903513 *)
```

Just to make sure:

```
test1 === test2 === test3 === test4
(* True *)
```

(Since I am stuck on Ver 10.0, I don't have access to `RepeatedTiming`, so this is the best I can do.)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I use V10.0 too.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps,

```
With[{u = Union @@ a}, a /. Thread[u -> Range[Length@u]]]
```

Comment: In my testing, `Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@a` is faster than `Union @@ a`, but it could be my particular choice of test list (i.e. `SeedRandom[0]; a = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {10000, 2}];`). Also, this version is not significantly faster than the OP's version. However, if instead you do `Dispatch@Thread[u -> Range[Length@u]]]`, it is much faster.

Comment: @march thank you...I unfortunately did not think deeply enough...I was not sure what the "size" of the problem was but accept entirely your comments. If you post  `Dispatch` answer i am happy to +1 :)

Comment: Well, I did post it, but I was hesitant to, since the construction is exactly your answer, with the extra addition of the hash table created by `Dispatch`.

Comment: @march sorry missed that...very instructive answer rather than my off the cuff one :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an incremental improvement on existing answers.

march's code as `fn0` for reference.

`fn1` should work on lists of any shape.

`fn2` assumes that your sublists are all the same length.

```
fn0[a_] := With[{b = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@a},
  a /. Dispatch@Thread[b -> Range@Length@b]]

fn1[a_] :=
  a /. AssociationThread[Ordering[#], #] & @ DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten @ a;

fn2[a_] :=
  Module[{flat, asc},
    flat = Flatten@a;
    asc = AssociationThread[Ordering[#], #] & @ DeleteDuplicates @ flat;
    asc ~Lookup~ flat ~Partition~ Length[First @ a]
  ]

a = RandomInteger[1*^6, {500000, 2}];

fn0[a] // RepeatedTiming // First
fn1[a] // RepeatedTiming // First
fn2[a] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.53
>
> 1.33
>
> 1.09
> ```

Comment: It's a big improvement. Thanks. Is the reason that `AssociationThread` is faster than `Dispatch`?

Comment: @Ice0cean If `AssociationThread` is faster I *think* (you should check) it is because we eliminate the separate `Thread` operation.  I'll try to remember to check it myself later but I'll probably forget.

Comment: ♦ I will check it.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1020, 3058}, {98, 98}, {599, 600}};
```

Using `PositionIndex`

```
Join @@@ ReplaceAll[PositionIndex[Union @@ a]] @ a
```

{{4, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}}

Speed test using Mr.Wizard's data

```
a = RandomInteger[1*^6, {500000, 2}];

Join @@@ ReplaceAll[PositionIndex[Union @@ a]] @ a; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

1.41